# Error When Trying To Insert New User With Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-directory-api

My script is failing with the following error when attempting to insert a new user through Google Apps Script:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.users.insert failed with error: Invalid Input: primary_user_email

The logger shows all variables in the wrapper are correct. I had this issue previously, and adding the global variable "sheet" at the beginning of the function had fixed it, but the bug is back.

Here's my code snippet:

```
//Global variables

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dVJQRSQZvAwZOAjde1wQsbaz77r4jle00v0_IREO2pE");
//New Employee Script Spreadsheet
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
//Sets New Employee Script as the active spreadsheet and binds it to the variable "ss"
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);

var firstName = sheet.getRange("A2");
var first = firstName.getValue();

var lastName = sheet.getRange("B2");
var last = lastName.getValue();

var userEmail = sheet.getRange("C2");
var email = userEmail.getValue();

var orgUnit = sheet.getRange("D2");
var unit = orgUnit.getValue();

//values are set to "first", "last", "email", and "unit"

    
function newUser() {
    //function newUser, this function will add a new user to the Google Directory

 sheet
 //calls the variable "sheet" to remind it where to look, shouldn't be needed, but the function failed without it, so better to just leave it in

  var user = [{
    //sets up the wrapper "user" that Google needs to insert a user, what follows are the details inside the wrapper
    
    "primaryEmail": email,
    //sets the variable "primaryEmail" to the global variable "email"

    "orgUnitPath": '/Staff/'+unit,
    //defines which org unit the staff will be created in, since this is for staff, all of them will be a sub-unit under "Staff"

    "name": {
      "givenName": first,
      //sets the variable "givenName" to the global variable "first"
      "familyName": last
      //sets the variable "familyName" the the gloabl variable "last"
  },
  //ends the wrapper for "name"

    "password": "ABCD.1234",
    //sets the new users password to "ABCD.1234"
    "changePasswordAtNextLogin": true,
    //Should prompt the user to change their password at their next login
  }];

   Logger.log(user);

  AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user); //This is the line that the error is reported at.
```

'

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (several variable declarations are misssing)

Comment: sorry, I added my global variable section